# How to edit a particular line of the csv file using PHP?

Tags: php, csv

I have a PHP script that allow users to upload their data. The first line of the csv file are the headers (fname, lname, age, address, email).

My plan is - after the users uploaded their csv, my script will run a function to check the spelling of the headers. If there are misspelled header, my script will correct it. I am using the code below to correct the headers:

```
   if (($file = fopen($csvFile , "r")) != FALSE) {
        $ctr = 0;
        $record = fgetcsv($file, 1024)) != FALSE) {
            if ($ctr == 0) {
                correctHeader($record);
                # write to new csv.
            } else {
                # write to new csv.
            }
        }
    }
```

After correcting, the value of the header and the succeeding lines will be appended on the new csv file. I think this step can be optimized, if I could just edit the first line of the csv (header) and skip the `# write to new csv` step.

Comment: You have the right idea here, but may I suggest using `fopen` option `w+` or similar so you wont need a 2nd file handle to make writes the file. Type `r` only opens the file for reading.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways I can think of is the following:

1. Use `fgets()` to get the first line of the file (instead of `fgetcsv()`).
2. Save the length of the line in bytes.
3. Parse the line with `str_getcsv()`.
4. Correct headers as needed.
5. Save headers into a new CSV file.
6. `fopen()` the original CSV file for reading.
7. `fseek()` the original CSV file handle to length of first line (saved in step 2) + 1.
8. `fopen()` the new CSV file for writing (appending actually).
9. `fread()` the original CSV file in the loop until EOF and `fwrite()` chunks into the new CSV file.
10. Fix bugs.
11. Have a pint. :)

Here's the code (minus the loop for reading):

```
<?php
$from = 'd.csv';
$to = 'd.good.csv';

$old = fopen($from, 'r');
if (!is_resource($old)) {
    die("Failed to read from source file: $from");
}

$headerLine = fgets($old);
$headerLine = fixHeaders($headerLine);

$new = fopen($to, 'w');
if (!is_resource($new)) {
    die("Failed to write to destination file: $new");
}
// Save the fixed header into the new file
fputs($new, $headerLine);
// Read the rest of old and save to new.
// Old file is already open and we are the second line.
// For large files, reading should probably be done in the loop with chunks.
fwrite($new, fread($old, filesize($from)));

// Close files
fclose($old);
fclose($new);

// Just an example
function fixHeaders($line) {
    return strtoupper($line);
}
```

Comment: You made a beautiful explanation you could also put the code